# 別のストーリーボードのNavigationControllerとViewControllerを関連つけたい

Tags: ios, storyboard

Storyboard上でNavigationControllerとViewControllerを RelationShipSegue, root view controller で関連付ける処理を、NavigationControllerとViewControllerがそれぞれ別のStoryboardにある場合はどのようにすればいいんでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

もしXcode7でターゲットがiOS9であれば、Storyboardから別のStoryboardを参照できるようになりました

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AddSBReference.html

ですが、iOS9より前のiOSでは利用できないので別のStoryboardを参照するにはコードで呼び出すしかないですね。例えばUIStoryboardのクラスメソッドstoryboardWithName:bundle:などを使います。

Answer (score 0):

ストーリボード間でセグエを設定することはできません。コード上で行うしかありません。